# ERROR when running airflow task: Log file does not exist Failed to fetch log file from worker. Request URL is missing an http:// or https:// protocol

Tags: python, airflow

I am running a DAG in airflow (Docker compose ) containing a

- DummyOperator : start
- PythonOperator : simple python function to print text
- DummyOperator : end

[image]

when I run the DAG I get this error  :

> *** Log file does not exist: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=TEST/run_id=manual__2023-03-16T20:02:49.256977+00:00/task_id=test/attempt=1.log
>
> *** Fetching from: http://:8793/log/dag_id=TEST/run_id=manual__2023-03-16T20:02:49.256977+00:00/task_id=test/attempt=1.log
>
> *** Failed to fetch log file from worker. Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the configuration is ok, the real problem was found that the dag task don't generate logs. So I used new dag to create task and it's all right.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35236588)